# c# Conditionnal features like Rust

Tags: c#, build

I have a question.

I have 3 projects `1 lib` and `2 program`

Both program reference this lib. But program 2 need less implementation than program 1

I would like a technic like features in rust, allowing conditionally build. ex:

```ini
# Cargo.toml
[features]
default = []
prog1 = []
```

```rust
// main.rs
struct A {
  #[cfg(feature = "prog1")]
  pub field_only_in_prog1;

  pub id;
}

#[cfg(feature = "prog1")]
struct StructOnlyInProg1;
```

I found conditionally build by constant, but it didn't work when constant his definded in program, or am I doing wrong.

ex:

```cs
class A {
  #if PROG_1
    string PropertyOnlyInProg1 { get; }
  #endif
}
#if PROG_1
  class BOnlyInProg1 {}
#endif
```

Thanks for reading and help.

Comment: You'd have to build two separate versions of the library. Even if you don't *need* all the features in both programs, is it actually a problem to include them in both?

Comment: There exist a concept of [application trimming](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/app-trimming-in-net-5/). But unless you assemblies are huge, why are you bothering? And if your assemblies *are* huge, you should consider splitting it.

Comment: My library isn't necessary huge but, a class can be implement an method come from interface come in huge library.
This implementation is needed when my classes is used in web api program but not in console program